# Not finding xml file after decompiling using apkstudio

Tags: xml, apk

I wanted to change the package name of an apk file built with app inventor.
I used apkstudio to decompile the file.
apkstudio creates a new folder, and inside of it are only the smali and the source folders and the jar file. The xml and the other folders that are supposed to be there are not.

I tried downloading other versions of apkstudio but the problem is still there.
what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using apktool first to decompile the apk and its resources. It will generate a folder where you placed the apk file at with the AndroidManifest.xml inside it ready to be edited. However changing an app's package name is not as easy as modifying the package string in the AndroidManfiest. To change a app's package name you're going to have to change the package name in the AndroidManifest and in the decompiled code. If you're using windows and have cygwin installed then boot up a terminal and type

```bash
find path/to/decompiled/apk/folder -type f -exec sed -e "s/current\\/package\\/name/new\\/package\\/name/g" {} +
```

and

```bash
find path/to/decompiled/apk/folder -type f -exec sed -e "s/current.package.name/new.package.name/g" {} +
```